# Classic asp button click on enter

Tags: asp-classic

I am new to Classic asp and trying to figure out some basic stuff. I have a form with a textbox and as soon as the user enters data in form and press enter, button click should happen. what attributes should i change in form tag to achieve this functionality??

Answer (score 0):

The button you place in the `form` should be a `submit` button.  In the `form` tag itself, you simply need to set the `id`, `method` and `action` attributes, similar to:

```html
<form id="mainForm" method="post" action="mypage.asp">
    <input type="text" name="myTextBox" />
    <button type="submit" id="submitForm" />
</form>
```

Your `input` (text) box and `submit` button should obviously lie between the open and close `form` tags.

Note here that there is no VB or JScript involved at this point.  That comes once you receive your post from the `form`.